# How do you make an add-in for Excel 2011 (Mac)

Tags: visual-studio, macos, excel, add-in

I would like to add a button to the Ribbon and have it perform some basic tasks when clicked. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  It looks like it is possible, but it is not.  The only proper add in for Excel 2011 Mac is provided with Excel, and the ability to show it in Excel Mac's ribbon is apparently hard-coded into the Excel Mac application.  None of the XML-based techniques for extending the Excel Mac ribbon work because the ribbon is hard-coded.  It looks like the Windows version, but it is nothing like it.

Obviously, it is hard to provide sources for a negative answer.  I have researched this topic carefully including contacting Microsoft support, and found that there is no compiler or IDE from Microsoft for this purpose.  You can certainly develop in VBA in Excel Mac, and you can make an XLA add-in, but you cannot access the ribbon.  You can create little square Mac toolbar icons, just as in Excel 98.

Answer (score -2):

Here are some useful links that will answer your question:

- how to [customize the ribbon](http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm)
- how to [customize the ribbon with vba](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php?105-Add-ribbon-programmatically-to-Excel-2010-using-VBA)
- how to [create an add in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140936%28v=office.10%29.aspx) (on MSDN)
- a clearer tuto on how to [create an addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx)

Please ask a more precise question if you want more precise help.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I am wondering if it is possible to make a proper add-in for Excel 2011, the Mac version. All these tutorials are for the PC version of Office only. Is it possible to make an add-in that works on the Mac version of Office?

Comment: seems like 2008 didn't support vba but 2011 does >> https://kis.kellogg.northwestern.edu/Pages/E2011addins.aspx

Comment: Those are links to the PC version. OP asked for Mac version.